# Update all user related data when user logs in (observable)

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, observable

I am working on an angular-application with authentication. The application has a dashboard which shows the username of the logged in user. The problem is, that when you login with a new user, it still shows the username of the last logged in user.

So it doesen't update the username (observable) when a user logs in. 
I think the problem is that I get the username in the `ngOnInit` methode.

How can I update all user related data?

**header.component.ts** (username should be shown)

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from '../../../core/auth.service';
import { Apollo } from 'apollo-angular';
import gpl from 'graphql-tag';

const registeredUser = gpl`
  query registeredUser {
    registeredUser {
      name
    }   
  }
`

@Component({
  selector: 'dashboard-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.css']
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {

  private user$;

  constructor(
    private authService : AuthService,
    private apollo : Apollo) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.user$ = this.apollo.watchQuery<any>({
      query: registeredUser
    })
      .valueChanges;
  }

  logout() {
    this.authService.logout();
  }

}
```

**AuthService**

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { JwtHelper } from 'angular2-jwt';
import { Apollo } from 'apollo-angular';
import gpl from 'graphql-tag';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

const register = gpl`
mutation($name: String!, $email_mobile: String!, $password: String!) {
  register(name: $name, email_mobile: $email_mobile, password: $password) {
    success
    token
    user {
      name
      email
      mobile
    }
    errors {
      message
      key
    }
  }
}
`;

const login = gpl`
mutation($email_mobile: String!, $password: String!) {
  login(email_mobile: $email_mobile, password: $password) {
    success
    token
    user {
      name
      email
      mobile
    }
    errors {
      message
      key
    }
  }
}
`;

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  
  constructor(
    private jwtHelper: JwtHelper,
    private apollo: Apollo,
    private router: Router) { }


  isLoggedIn(): boolean {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token');

    if(!token)
      return false;

    // Check whether the token is expired and return
    // true or false
    return !this.jwtHelper.isTokenExpired(token);
  }

  async register(name: string, email_mobile: string, password: string) {

    let regInfo = {};

    await this.apollo.mutate({
      mutation: register,
      variables: {
        name,
        email_mobile,
        password
      }
    }).subscribe(({data}) => {
      
      const regData = data.register;

      if(regData.success) {
        // set token to Local Storage
        localStorage.setItem("token", regData.token);
        this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
      } else {
        regInfo["errors"] = regData.errors;
      }
      regInfo["success"] = regData.success;
    });

    return regInfo;
  }

  async login(email_mobile: string, password: string) {
    let regInfo = {};

    await this.apollo.mutate({
      mutation: login,
      variables: {
        email_mobile,
        password
      }
    }).subscribe(({data}) => {

      const regData = data.login;
      if(regData.success) {
        // set token to Local Storage
        localStorage.setItem("token", regData.token);
        regInfo["user"] = regData.user;
        this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
      } else {
        regInfo["errors"] = regData.errors;
      }
      regInfo["success"] = regData.success;
    });

    return regInfo;
  }

  logout(){
    localStorage.removeItem("token");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should subscribe to changes in your Apollo class, not just take them one off. Your code retrieves the variable, but does not stay to listen in on the pipe, when another user flies by.

**Your code**

```
this.user$ = this.apollo.watchQuery<any>({
      query: registeredUser
    })
      .valueChanges;
```

**What I envision**

```
this.apollo.valueChanges.subscribe(
      ({ data }) => {
        this.user$ = [...data.user];
      }
    );
```

And remember kids, please unsusbcribe from your pipes!

**Read more about GraphQL Subscriptions here!**

https://alligator.io/angular/graphql-subscriptions/

Comment: Thanks for the tip to unsubscribe. But it still shows the old username. I think you are understanding it wrong. The username in the database doesn't change. The only thing that changes is the logged in user.
I think the problem is that i subscribe in the ngOnInit methode. And when I login with a new user the ngOnInit methode had already been called.

Comment: Since you are dealing with observables, you subscribe on your ngOnInit method to the pipeline, that shoots logged in users. So if you are connected to the pipeline and you change the user, then you push the new user into the pipeline and the component catches it on the other end.

Comment: How do you mean this with "push new user into the pipeline"? Can you give me an example please. =D